# ms access highlighting keywords

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a macro/code that highlights certain keywords that are identified within the macro/code. I want to place this macro/code into MS Access 2010 so users are able to search for these certain keywords instead of manually looking at each record for the particular keyword.

My question is how do I get the keywords highlighted and shown in the database? Would I add the code to the "After Update Event" of the notes field?

[image]

Comment: The attached code picture shows Excel code, so it is hard to guess what and you are trying to do and where.

Comment: Please post your as text, never an image :)

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim TargetList

TargetList = Array("keyword", "keyword2") ' put list of terms to find here

For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
.Text = TargetList(i)
.Format = True
.MatchCase = True
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Loop

End With
Next

End Sub